# Update script on Pi that fetches new files from Github?

Tags: github, raspberry-pi

I'm developing a hobby thing for Raspberry Pi. It gets data from a racing game (Project CARS 2) on consoles, and stores the players laptimes in a db. They can be viewed a in a browser (php). The project consists mainly of a .NET exe, some php files, and a MariaDB. Currently I'm distributing it as an image file, that the user can download and write to a micro sdhc card.

Question: Is there a way to run a script that checks github if certain files have been updated? And if so, download them and overwrite the old files?

Github here: https://github.com/Maskmagog/projectcalc

The php files should be in /var/www/html/ on the Pi. The other directories are in /home/pi/.

I don't want to release a new image file for updates, as that would wipe users local databases. Thankful for any pointers in the right direction. I'm new to programming, and Github in particular. Thanks.

EDIT: Raspberry Pi runs standard Raspbian Stretch.
EDIT 2: Looks like maybe a 'git pull' can do this? It is not installed by 'git clone', would a 'git pull' still work? Sorry this is very new to me, I'm trying to learn about git commands.

Comment: if it wasn't deployed using git then you cannot use `git pull` to fetch updates. I would personally go with some deploying tool. Assuming you know php you can try [deployer](https://deployer.org/)  and wright simple script that you call whenever you want to update your app on raspberry pi.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that!